# How does the Countdown clock work?

Tags: countdown

In the UK television show [CountDown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_%28game_show%29), the clock appears to run clockwise from 12 o'clock down to six o'clock (see [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2dhD9zR6hk)).  Although I have never seen how the clock hand returns to the 12 o'clock point. After a round the camera seems to focus on the presenters, and contestants, thus when the next round is played everything is reset.

Possibilities;

- The hand completes the whole circumference of the clock, returning to the top
- It reverses direction to go back
- A technician pulls the hand from the face, and places it back to the top. (Least likely because of the disruption).

Answer (score 7):

It looks like it just winds around and back whenever the camera isn't looking. You can see this in the [8 Out Of 10 Cats do Countdown special (16 08 13)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEgvhc0nivs&t=11m53s) where Jimmy gets excited and accidentally starts the countdown and they reset it with the camera still on it.

Comment: I remember seeing the same thing happen on the regular Countdown (probably a behind the scenes program or something similar).

Comment: The exact incident happens at about 11:54 on the linked video.